# Rabbit MQ localhost to IP Address access for use server to other systems Connection Issue?

Tags: rabbitmq

1) I was installed Rabbit MQ server in my windows machine.
2) Enable admin UI successfully.
3) Working fine in localhost and default guest user.
4) After that i created another admin named bala and changed in rabbitmq.conf file 
'127.0.0.1' to '0.0.0.0' my ip address

But my system working fine i can send and receive messages. but another system not able to access to send message in my local area network.

i am facing => SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
this Issue

My Code is here =>

```
 internal ConnectionFactory MQFactory;
        internal IConnection MQConnection;
        internal IModel MQChannel;

     var server = "192.168.1.7";
            var password = "bala";
            var username = "bala";
            var virtualhost = "/";
            var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = server, Password = password, UserName = username, RequestedHeartbeat = 10 };
            MQConnection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the RabbitMQ config file, usually you will find it at %APPDATA%/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq.config, add below line

```
[{rabbit,[{loopback_users,[]}]}].
```

PS. don't miss to add the dot at the end.

Comment: Thanks @RajN . rabbitmqctl status
rabbit@DESKTOP-F5BTUV4:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on DESKTOP-F5BTUV4
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli57@DESKTOP-F5BTUV4'
 * effective user's home directory: C:\Users\BALA
 * Erlang cookie hash: zGOYNL/a86NtdzyP7ZsyjQ==
Now also not working . I checked Command prombt too. It will throw this error